# Authentication and websockets

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm doing this -

1. Load single page application - an apollo client is initialised with a websocket and http link.  This happens when the user is logged out, let's say.
2. The user then logs in without a page reload.  The graphql response now contains the session cookie.

Problem - whilst subsequent http requests include the session cookie the websocket connection does not.

How do people solve this problem?

I'm guessing either make all communication with the server via websockets, or, create a new apollo client upon successful sign in and use this for subscriptions.

This is for a chat app.  I'm using http and websockets at the moment.